# What is the meaning of the expression "A one paper kid" or "One paper kid"

Tags: etymology, expressions

This is a country song title by the late Walter Martin Cowart and has been covered by several artists.  Is this a local expression or slang term perhaps used in the American southern states?

Comment: There are one paper towns - perhaps that is a play on that

Answer (score 5):

Given that the [song lyrics](http://www.cowboylyrics.com/lyrics/harris-emmylou/one-paper-kid-6374.html) contain references like *light it again* and *rollin' again*, the paper in question is likely cigarette paper.

As for the meaning of the expression, another phrase in the lyrics says *"times were so lean,"* so it's likely a metaphor for that -- the "kid" (some Western connotations there as well) is down to his last cigarette paper, or economizes by rolling cigarettes with only one paper.

Answer (score 5):

In the 70s, many people stuck two regular-size rolling papers together to make a larger one, to make rolling a joint easier. Using one paper was a mark of skill and experience.

Answer (score 2):

Rolling a joint with one cigarette paper was a sign of virtuosity even before the 70s. Anyone who spent much time rolling joints would recognize this allusion right away.

Answer (score 0):

This is a poignant song about hard times, dead end places and wasted lives.  A young man, idle and dreaming of better, is so practiced rolling joints that he can do so with one paper and is so good at it he is nick-named for the skill. We know it is pot, not tobacco, because after death there are "no Camels"... a commercial brand of cigarette implying that in Life he had smoked Camels for his tobacco. His aimless life is cut short by a drunk or inattentive driver. He "wrote on a rock" ie. sealed his fate, by "rolling again" and again and again.  The story teller helplessly sings from the same predicament knowing his own future will be no better.

Answer (score -3):

"One paper kid" may refer to a literal kid make of paper while "A one paper kid" is either slang or poor English.

Comment: ‘A one-paper kid’ is perfectly good English. “A literal kid make of paper”, on the other hand, is poor English, and is a very unlikely interpretation of the lyrics here.